# Posting to a user's Yammer feed using Open Graph

Tags: yammer

I successfully posted an activity to the activity feed using the activity API and open graph. However, I do not see a post on the actor's Yammer feed when I click the user's name. I assumed that the activity API would post there as well because of what I read in the documentation:

*This activity will appear in the Yammer Activity Stream Ticker (shown above) **and will be delivered to the actor, the actor’s followers and the people specified in the “users” list***

Here is the data I'm posting to the API. You can see that I'm also adding the actor as one of the 'users' who should get the post (look right after `"private"=>"false"`). Still no good.

```
$text=array("activity"=>
array("actor"=>
array("name"=>$res->user->full_name,
"email"=>$res->user->contact->email_addresses[0]->address),
"action"=>"domain:action",
"object"=>array("url"=>"https://website.com","type"=>"domain:object","title"=>"post"),
"private"=>"false",
"users"=>array("email"=>$res->user->contact->email_addresses[0]->address,"name"=>$res->user->full_name),
"message"=>"my first post"));
```

$text is then json_encoded. Here is the curl call:

```
$url="https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/activity.json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$jtext);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$accToken,'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here is the response to the above curl request:

`stdClass Object
(
    [action_id] => xxxxxxxxx
    [object_id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [actor_id] => xxxxxxxxxx
)`

The Activity Stream Post is working fine as far as I can see, just wondering what code I'm missing (or API call) to post on the user's feed. This is written in PHP and needs to stay in PHP. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that I wasn't using the messages API for posting to the user's wall.Here is working code based on the current API specification. I hope this helps someone else.

NOTE- the message has to be called 'body' and you need to set the 'Content-Type: application/json' in the header:

```
    $text=array("body"=>"This is a test post");
    $jtext=json_encode($text);
    $url="https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$jtext);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$accToken,'Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```